# $\frac{ds}{dt}$ for $s=t^3+at^2s+bts^2+cs^3$

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-differentiation, cubics

Given a point $P_1=(s_1,t_1)$ on a cubic curve given by $s=t^3+at^2s+bts^2+cs^3$ I need to calculate the slope of the tanget line at $P_1$. This is part of a proof  of the Nagell-Lutz Theorem.
The book states that the slope equals
$$\alpha=\frac{ds}{dt}(P_1)= \frac{3t_1^2+2at_1s_1+bs_1^2}{1-at_1^2-2bt_1s_1-3cs_1^2}$$

But I have no idea how to calculate this derivate, since it seems like I can not solve this given equation for $s$.

I also tried to apply the implicit function theorem. For
$$f(t,s)= t^3+at^2s+bts^2+cs^3-s$$ I know
$f(t_1,s_1)=0$. Obviously
$$D_sf(t,s)=(at^2+2bts+3cs^2-1)$$
but I struggle to verify that $\det D_sf(t_1,s_1)\not=0$. And even if I could I am not sure how I would receive this final form for $\frac{ds}{dt}$, since this theorem does not provide a closed form for $s$ in a implicit area around $P_1$, but only states that there is a closed form. Or am I messing up something?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{dbts^2}{ dt}= bt\frac{ds^2}{ dt}+bs^2\frac{dt}{ dt}=2bts\frac{ ds}{ dt}+ bs^2.~~~~~$ You can do the same for other terms.

Comment: Thank you, that worked out. But can you maybe give an formal justification why that works? For me it looks like a physicist trick. At least it is not obvious for me why this is right. Thank you

Comment: $\frac{dbts^2}{ dt}= bt\frac{ds^2}{ dt}+bs^2\frac{dt}{ dt}$ using product rule and $$\frac{ds^2}{ dt}=\frac{ds^2}{ ds}\cdot \frac{ds}{dt}=2s\frac{ ds}{ dt}$$